# CE Img template debugging doesnt display in depth info

Tags: ce-image

Following the directions listed here:
http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/troubleshooting

I set up a dummy template with a missing image, so I could see the debug information, but I never got the "***  CE Image debug:". Ive copied my debug text below:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cc2c9d014550f52d1e20

Currently CE Img isnt displaying any images at all, but until I see the debug message, I cant get much further!

Comment: Which version of CE Image are you running?

Comment: I am currently running 2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

[CE Image 2.1.3](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/change-log#v2.1.3) was released in June of 2011. There have been numerous updates and releases since that time. Upgrading to the latest version will allow the in-depth debug information to show.